# not call onActivityResult in Fragment, after return from gallery

Tags: android, android-permissions

in my fragment I select photo from gallery

in Manifest.xml

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

beforе this my app show permission dialog. I press Allow

[image]

```
public class EditProfileFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
 private void choosePhotoFromGallery() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}
```

but method

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult_requestCode = " + requestCode + ", resultCode = " + resultCode + ", data = "
                    + AndroidUtil.intent2String(data));
```

**not call** in **Fragment** after return to my app

Not print text : `onActivityResult_requestCode`

But method onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) call in **Activity**.
But I need to call this method in fragment.

here request permission dialog:

```
  private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int writeExternalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int readExternalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (writeExternalStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (readExternalStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (camera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "checkAndRequestPermissions_listPermissionsNeeded(" + listPermissionsNeeded.size() + ")");
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "checkAndRequestPermissions_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQ_CODE");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()])
                    , WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQ_CODE);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Did you specified these permissions in manifest and read external storage??

Comment: Yes, I updated my post

Comment: put log and check any exception is occurred.

Comment: put permission read external storage in manifest...

Comment: are you using fragment? from where choosePhotoFromGallery() is called

Comment: @APP Yes, from fragment

Comment: @ShivamOberoi I updated my post. Not help. Same result

Comment: try fragment.onActivityResult

Comment: Method onActivityResult call in activity. But I need to call this method in fragment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put this in your Activity on Activity Result

```
   Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

what it will do is to call the fragment onActivityResult of your fragment. So you will have selection data in your fragment

Inside Fragment Start Activity For Result

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Now in Activity

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Inside Fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        //  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "Activit Result");
        if (resultCode == -1) {
        }
}
```

Hoping that will help

Comment: Method onActivityResult call in activity. But I need to call this method in fragment

Comment: how it will work, 
in fragment you will call getActivity.startActivityForResult. When you select the photo, it will send data to activity, and in activity onActivityResult paste this code, so it will send data back to your fragment where you can consume that data

Comment: Before android 6.0 my code was work. Now I need to update my code. Why? Google change politic to work with photo?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling from fragment then try this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_tag);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```